# Jenkinsx - 503 service temporary available

Tags: jenkins-x

I set up the CI CD pipeline on GKE using JenkinsX. The build step is successful, but if I hit the staging URL, it shows me the page with 503 Service temporarily unavailable. I know that JenkinsX deploys the application behind nginx. So do I need to any configuration so that nginx can lookup the application? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

sounds like your Jenkins is not running. A number of things could be wrong (not enough capacity or Persistent Volumes).

See the diagnostic guide in the FAQ: 
https://jenkins-x.io/faq/issues/#jenkins-x-does-not-startup